# What is a "single kubectl list object" as mentioned in jsonnet documentation?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The [jsonnet documentation > Using Jsonnet With Kubernetes](https://jsonnet.org/articles/kubernetes.html) says:

> Use YAML stream output, multi-file output, or a **single kubectl list object**. This latter option is provided by Kubernetes without requiring any special support from Jsonnet. It allows us to **group several Kubernetes objects into a single object**. This is the most popular option because it does not require intermediate files, and other tools don't always reliably support YAML streams.

YAML streams is putting several resources separated with `---` , multi-file output is self-explanatory, but I never heard of a "kubectl list object".

If I google it I only get [1](https://jsonnet.org/articles/kubernetes.html) and [2](https://sre.google/workbook/configuration-specifics/) and they don't really explain what is a "kubectl list object".

So,  What is a **single kubectl list object** in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The folowing answer comes from a [conversation](https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C981W2HD3/p1697797708999419?thread_ts=1697796910.539769&cid=C981W2HD3) on the Kubernetes #kapitan channel with @ademaria and [Types(kinds)](https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/C981W2HD3/p1697797708999419?thread_ts=1697796910.539769&cid=C981W2HD3).

"kubectl list object" is a kubectl client-only feature (see [1](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds)):

> Note that kubectl and other tools sometimes output collections of resources as kind: List. Keep in mind that **kind: List is not part of the Kubernetes API**; it is exposing an implementation detail from **client-side code** in those tools, **used to handle groups of mixed resources**.

you can write

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  ...
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
```

and you can `kubectl apply -f xxx.yaml` that and kubectl will at the client side convert that before applying it via the Kubernetes API (which does not have any `kind:List`,etc)

So the jsonnet documentation is refering to the fact that you can create a `v1/List` object (**a single kubectl list object**) with all the resources inside and pass that to kubectl, the same way you will pass a yaml stream.

It's list object or list resource but since it's only client-side they emphasize that by saying  its a **kubectl list object**